# Default value of _start

Tags: c, assembly, x86, ld, att

Let's say I have the following assembly program:

```
.globl _start
_start:
    mov $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

And I assemble/link it with:

```sh
$ as file.s
$ ld a.out -o a
```

This will run fine, and return the status code of 0 to linux. However, when I remove the line `.globl start` I get the following error:

> `ld`: warning: cannot find entry symbol `_start`; defaulting to `0000000000400078`

What does `0000000000400078` mean? And also, if `ld` expects the `_start` symbol on entry, why is it even necessary to declare `.globl _start` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, when I remove the line `.globl _start` ...

The `.globl` line means that the name `_start` is "visible" outside the file `file.s`. If you remove that line, the name `_start` is only for use inside the file `file.s` and in a larger program (containing multiple files) you could even use the name `_start` in multiple files.

(This is similar to `static` variables in C/C++: If you generate assembler code from C or C++, the difference between real global variables and `static` variables is that there is a `.globl` line for the global variables and no `.globl` line for `static` variables. And if you are familiar with C, you know that `static` variables cannot be used in other files.)

The linker (`ld`) is also not able to use the name `_start` if it can be used inside the file only.

> What does `0000000000400078` mean?

Obviously `0x400078` is the address of the first byte of your program. `ld` assumes that the program starts at the first byte if no symbol named `_start` is found.

> ... why is it even necessary to declare `.globl _start`?

It is not guaranteed that `_start` is located at the first byte of your program.

Counterexample:

```
.globl _start

write_stdout:
    mov $4, %eax
    mov $1, %ebx
    int $0x80
    ret

exit:
    mov $1, %eax
    mov $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
    jmp exit

_start:
    mov $text, %ecx
    mov $(textend-text), %edx
    call write_stdout
    mov $text2, %ecx
    mov $(textend2-text2), %edx
    call write_stdout
    call exit

text:
    .ascii "Hello\n"
textend:
text2:
    .ascii "World\n"
textend2:
```

If you remove the `.globl` line, `ld` will not be able to find the `_start:` line and assume that your program starts at the first byte - which is the `write_stdout:` line!

... and if you have multiple `.s` files in a larger program (or even a combination of `.s`, `.c` and `.cc`), you don't have control about which code is located at the first byte of your program!

Comment: cool, great answer thank you very much! One question: how would I use `ld` to enter at a particular symbol if no `.globl` is defined? For example, something like (from your example above) `$ ld -enter="exit" file.s` in which case the script doesn't do anything it just exit. Finally, why the `jmp exit` at the end of the `exit` section?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 You may define a different entry point than `_start` using `-e` (example: `ld -e begin ...`). However, in this case you'll have to declare the other symbol using `.globl`. Without using `.globl` at all, you have nearly no chance. The `jmp exit` is habit: Before I worked with Linux I worked with another OS where the "exit" system call (in Linux: `eax=1`) sometimes failed and had to be repeated.

Comment: got it, thanks. So in other words, at least one symbol needs o be `.globl` in the assembly file that's being linked, right?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Not necessarily, but it wouldn't be very useful not to have any global symbols.  One example I could think off is inserting copyright information using the `.comment` section.  In such a case, no global symbol might be provided by the file providing this `.comment` section.  That said, I recommend you to familiarise yourself with the GNU ld manual.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249  .globl in gnu assembler simply makes the label global so that it is visible outside that object (so it can be linked or otherwise seen if needed).  _start is a special label in the gnu world that the linker looks for.  Your code will still get linked even if you have no global labels, it just means you either know how you are getting at that data in a way that is not typical.  (link at a specific address then access it at that address not using the label).  or you are just adding stuff to the binary that isnt being used.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 bootstrap code and the linker script are often intimately related, they are a pair you often cant analyze one without the other.   So to extend the recommendation of reading the ld docs, also make some very small asm programs and linker scripts and familiarize yourself with how they interact as well as how the ld tool itself handles objects and not just the linker script itself.

Comment: If you are doing a (small) project in assembly language for a microcontroller (in a single file) is an example where you might not need any global labels.  _start is not useful for that type of target as you dont have an operating system loading the program and needing to know the entry point, instead the hardware dictates the boot mechanism and you need to build/link to match, so an entry of the first item in the binary is not uncommon.   exception not the rule though, even with mcu projects you generally have multiple objects that call each other.

Comment: @old_timer thanks for the suggestion. Other than reading the `man ld`, are there any good resources you can recommend for learning (for a beginner) more about `ld` and `linker scripts` ?

Comment: there are countless bare metal examples out there as well as C libraries that have linker scripts and bootstrap code.